# I'm a begginer at python and i have this problem: ModuleNotFoundError. Can anyone help me?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm tryong to import a class to my main python programm(alien_invaision.py) but for some reason it gives me the error: ModuleNotFoundError, event though i'm following a book that says to do it this way. Mabye i should use a different IDE. Right now im using IDLE. So i could mabye try sublime text or something.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 245)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

My code for settings.py is this:

```
class Settings:

        def __init__(self):
            self.screen_width = 1200
            self.screen_height = 800
            self.bg_color = (230, 230, 245)
```

and my code for ship.py is this:

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

So im not sure what to do. can anyone help?

Comment: If it is a library, you need to install it. Try `pip install pygame` if `pygame` is a library. If these are other Python files (source codes) they must be in the same directory

Comment: Please provide the following information:  (1) the full error message - Copy and then paste into your question as code; (2) The filename and fullpath to the file containing the AlienInvasion class; (3)The filename and the fullpath  to the file containing Settings class; and (4)The filename and full path to the file containing the Ship class.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fox_ski_/Alien_Invasion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from settings import Settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting pygame module not found error, you need to install  **pygame** using pip

> **pip install pygame**

your rest of the code works fine.

**Update:**
you need to place all the below custom modules in same directory.

- alien_invaision.py
- settings.py
- ship.py

Comment: Are you sure? I have pygame installed. It's telling me that it cant find the modules that i made like 'settings' or 'ship'. I do have pygame though because i made a few other games using pygame.

Comment: post the complete error. also can you share your modules structure, how you have defined?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a file called `__init__.py` in your directory so that python treats it as a module.

You can include code in the `__init__.py` or leave it blank. But it must be there.

Post your directory structure as @itprorh66 mentioned, which will help in narrowing down the issue and check if this works for you. Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to the documentation